# Running Java code in Eclipse without main

Tags: java, eclipse, class, program-entry-point

I have a Java project(running in Eclipse) without main method and need to debug and see which is the caller class and the flow of the program. How do I start?

It is a simple project and does not contain any web/tomcat related data.

---

Thank you for your responses. I am new to StackOverflow and so pardon my writing and asking questions.

I am including packages and trying to create objects of a class, but it is not recognizing the classes. All the classes are public.

Comment: You can't have a flow without a main method. That's where the first call has to start.

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to run a Java SE application without starting with public static void main. If you want to debug the code of a library or framework you need to create a main method and call the code from there.

Comment: I am including packages and trying to create objects of a class, but it is not recognizing the classes. All the classes are public.

Comment: What do you mean with it is not recognizing the classes? What error do you have? Could you upload your project online?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look to [JUnit](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/junit-tutorials/). If you just want to debug your code is what you normally have to do.

Answer (score 1):

Since Java requires all methods and variables to be within classes, the JVM needs a starting point that exists before any objects are initialized. Therefore, main must be static and public for the JVM to find it. Unlike C++, the main method does not return a status code, so it is of return type void rather than int.